# What would cause my dishwasher to leak when it starts filling?

Tags: leak, dishwasher

my Maytag DW-2 dishwasher started leaking water from a small hole under, near the back and to the left whenever it starts filling with water. It must leak +-1 cup then stops leaking for the duration of the wash. Any idea why it would do that?

[image]

---

Update:

I have 2 more photos:

[image]

the inside lock looks like an X inside an O. Presumably the ends of the X should fit in the 4 notches to take it out but it seems that a special tool must be required to twist it in place.

this is where it leaks:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of where it is leaking from?

Comment: I do, how do I show it?

Comment: If you edit the question, there should be a button to add an image.  If you don't have the button (not sure how much rep you need to add images), you can post the image to imgur, flickr, or some other image hosting site. Then add the link to the image either as a comment, or in an edit to the question.

Comment: it won't let me do it cuz I'm new. Here's a link to the pix on flick: http://www.flickr.com/photos/11533240@N07/6647338393/in/photostream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad Seal! Or cracked pipe.

**You will need to take it out completely.**

Properly dismantle it  in and open space and trace/examine the source while the power is on

### (this can be dangerous so do not take chances)

If it only happens on the start- maybe it the inlet pipe cracked, seal perished.

If you do not feel comfortable with dissembling it call a recommended local service man.

Comment: I found the problem: the injector seal ring leaks. Now, if I can just figure out how do remove it...

Comment: Put in a photo of where it is.. it could not be that difficult? atleast you know the problem now. Please consider upvoting or accepting answer if a post has helped you.

Comment: I put 2 photos here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/11533240@N07/6648458069/in/photostream

the inside lock looks like an X inside an O.
Presumably the ends of the X should fit in the 4 notches to take it out but it seems that a special tool must be required to twist it in place.

the outside pix is here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/11533240@N07/6648457897/in/photostream
this is where it leaks

Comment: maybe I can just apply some sealant (silicone) around it...

Comment: You can try- use water resistant silicone and clean the area on the outside well with alcohol(not spirits will remove paint) and then apply the silicon around the pipe and injector seal in an even way- But it would be better to replace the seal.

Comment: I just put in a silicone seal, we'll see tomorrow if it works.
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @dan Hope you don't mind, I added your photos to the original question

Comment: no problem, I hope it helps someone else. BTW, I think I know how to take the whole thing out + seal (but it's too late now that I have put the silicone): you need to remove the black tube and turn the whole inlet (translucide) section 45 degrees

Comment: Just checked the unit this morning and it is fixed.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I see no buttons or area to do that. I saw a little grey arrow wich I clicked, is that it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

To remove the injector is very easy: pull the hose away from the molded U and at the same time, pull the injector away from the side then rotate clockwise a half turn to line up the hex.  But the leak is not at the seal; water backs up to the vent on the injector and runs down the injector.  I lowered the water flow and it stopped leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Inside this maytag fill injecter there is some sediment inside just clean the sediments and should not leak any more

Comment: Can you explain how sediment is causing a leak?